# Append "\n" to all elements except last in Ruby array

Tags: ruby, concatenation

I have an Array of Hashes that look like this:

```
texts = [{:text => 'my text', :width => 123}, {:text => 'my other text', :width => 200}]
```

I want to have a final text that would look like this:

```
my_final_text = 'my text\nmy other text'
```

I have tried doing this:

```
def concat_breakline(texts)
  final_text = ""
  texts.each do |text|
    final_text << text[:text] + "\n"
  end
end
```

But this would add "\n" to the last element, and I want to avoid that. How could I solve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

```
texts.collect { |text| text[:text] }.join("\n")
```

The `join` method adds things in the middle but not the end.